# This jQuery plugin does not recognize Persian letters and numbers. Is there a problem with my code? Or from somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, plugins

I will posted my code below and I am using inputmask.js which is a jQuery plugin to restrict inputs.  Please help and I will also try to do more of this on my own.

```js
<script>
    Inputmask.extendDefinitions({
        //Persian character and numbers (and space!)
        'f': {
            validator: "[۰-۹\u060C-\u0638\u0639-\u0648\u06A9\u06AF\u06CC\u067E\u0686\u064A\u0649\u0626\u0698 ]",
            cardinality: 1
        },

        'n':
    {
          validator:"[0-9]",
    },

    'm':
    {
        validator:"[۰-۹]",
    },

    'z':
    {
        validator:"[۱-۹]",
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you see the unexpected token error?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no error . even in inspectelement I could not find an error. Everything looks right but it does not work properly

Comment: When you hit Run code snippet, you do not see an error?

Comment: Maybe it is a browser compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because the version of inputmask.And here is a working demo:

1.copy the `/dist/jquery.inputmask.js` to your own project in the [link](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/5.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.js)

2.use the jquery in your view:

```
<input id="input1"/>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            Inputmask.extendDefinitions({
                //Persian character and numbers (and space!)
                'f': {
                    validator: "[۰-۹\u060C-\u0638\u0639-\u0648\u06A9\u06AF\u06CC\u067E\u0686\u064A\u0649\u0626\u0698]",
                    cardinality: 1
                },
            });
            $("#input1").inputmask("f{*}");
            
        });
 </script>
}
```

result:
[image]